# How to express "everything that is x" in MPL?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I know I can express "everyone is A" as:

P: is a person
$$ \forall x (Px \implies Ax) $$

And I can express "everyone who's A is B" as:

$$ \forall x ((Px \land Ax) \implies Bx) $$

But how can I express "everyone who's A"? If I were to take only the first part of the previous statement it would mean "everything is a person and A" instead of just "everyone who's A":

$$ \forall x (Px \land Ax) $$

Comment: “Everyone who’s A” is not a sentence

Comment: How's it not a sentence?

Comment: $\forall x (Px \land Ax)$ would be correct. It says every person who is A, assuming A is a subset of P. It picks out this set: $\{x\in P: A(x)\}$.

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães In logic, sentences have truth values. "Everyone who's A is B" is a sentence: it can be true, or it can be false (e.g. if there is somebody who is A but not B). "Everyone who's A" cannot be said to be true or false.

Comment: @Z.A.K. if you want to add your comment as an answer ill accept it. It helped me a tone.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost I can't assume A is a subset of P, unfortunately.

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães "everyone who is A" can be paraphrased in the following way: "Every person who is A" you can verify that the two sentences are equivalent, which means the set you want to pick out is: $\{x\in P: x\in A\}$.  What you are calling a "sentence" is a set, not a proposition.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost your comment makes a lot of sense, but if I understood it correctly, "everyone who is A" can't be represented in monadic predicate logic, right? Only in sets?

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães Well, set theory is in the language of predicate logic, so no. You can definitely state it in the language of predicate logic: $\forall x (Px \land Ax)$, the very last line in your question is correct.

Comment: Oh maybe a better way to put it then would be: it cannot be represented as a proposition, only as a set. Right?

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães Please look at the answer I left, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is where we are at: How to say, "everyone who is $A$". Everyone who is $A$ is not really a proposition in and of itself. It's a collection of objects in some particular domain of discourse.

So, we can define the following predicate $\forall x(Qx \iff (Ax \land Px))$, this is a proposition. Which set-theoretically says that $Q=\{x\in P: Ax\}$. Either $Q$ is empty or populated, in the language of predicate logic, $\not \exists x Qx=1$ or $\exists x Qx=1$.

Answer (score 1):

"Everyone who's A" is not a sentence, because it has no truth-value.